# the conflict when link openssl-win x64 static library

Tags: openssl, 64-bit

project::`https://github.com/kiyolee/openssl1_1-win-build`

When I compiled an  MFC project in VS2019 using the static library of openssl for x64，the error is as follows:

```
1>****.obj : error LNK2019: 无法解析的外部符号 X509_SIG_getm，函数 "int __cdecl ***(char *,char *,char *)" (?digestData2DER@@YAHPEAD00@Z) 中引用了该符号
1>libcrypto-1_1-static.lib : warning LNK4272: 库计算机类型“x86”与目标计算机类型“x64”冲突
1>未使用的库:
1>  libcrypto-1_1-static.lib
```

I have successfully compiled the static library linked to the x64 version of openssl and checked it out from the corresponding  folder named x64/debug, and the file is no problem.
What went wrong?